# Attempted to assign to readonly property Error when using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

my slice and reducer :

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const TransactionsListSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'transactions_list',
  initialState: {
    value: []
  },
  reducers: {
    saveTransactionsList: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload
    }
  }
})

export const { saveTransactionsList } = TransactionsListSlice.actions

export default TransactionsListSlice.reducer
```

```
let transactions_list = useSelector(state => state.transactions_list.value);
```

when trying to update my transactions_list with new data i have the below error:
Attempted to assign to readonly property.what is wrong?

Comment: The code looks good. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: even before update my redux state, when i put the redux value into an new array(let my_array = [... transactions_list]) and make some change i got the error, but when i define an array in my component every thing work as expected. note: i need change the array very deeply some times, maybe related or not @slideshowp2